# synchronize 2 Different Prestashop WebSites warehouse

Tags: mysql, web-services, prestashop

I just wondering if it's possible to set up 2 different websites with 2 different databases, filled with the same quantity stock.

I have this 2 websites (website1.com and website2.it) hosted in 2 different location but they share the same product ID and the same quantity from the warehouse.

Each websites use the Advanced stock management.

Now, it's possible with the webservice or a cron, to have the same quantity in both databases?

It's possible to set up a unique movement and synchronize them?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this module developed by me that do exactly that: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/stock-supplier-management/17740-shops-stock-synchronizer.html

Good luck.

Comment: So, I can have two shop in two different hosting and share the quantities information of every product only by id??

Comment: Enables synchronization of products stock from several shops by product reference. If product quantities are shared by several shops, there's no need to update them all manually. It sync by product reference, not ID. You can see a demo video en link too. Regards

Comment: If the Product have different combination, every combination have a different ref, the Modules work anyway?

Comment: Yes. Check demo video for all options.